# how to make space within span show up

Tags: html

I'm trying to set background color for a whitespace within a span. But it won't show up when the whitespace span happens to be at the point when line wraps.

**HTML**

```
asdfghjklkqowbvaa<span> </span>a
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
}

span {
  background-color: black;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/khoan/Ejaws/)

Comment: Add a `&nbsp;` character inside it. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ejaws/2/

Comment: If you add a &nbsp; to the span it will not break the string: *N*on*B*reaking*SP*ace. And I don't think that will be the desired resut.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Alter your css for the span to show white spaces, just like in the `<pre>` tag.
Take a look at the different [white-space options](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)

```
span {
    background-color: black;
    white-space:pre;
}
```

From the mentioned resource here is a nice table what the different options for `white-space` will do:

```
               New lines    Spaces and tabs   Text wrapping
normal         Collapse     Collapse          Wrap
pre            Preserve     Preserve          No wrap
nowrap         Collapse     Collapse          No wrap
pre-wrap       Preserve     Preserve          Wrap
pre-line       Preserve     Collapse          Wrap
```

If you add a `&nbsp;` to your span, the string will not break anymore on your space but instead 'glue' the two parts together, without wrapping the string on the space.

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap` is a better option if you want the space to remain at the end of the line. `white-space: pre` will force the space onto the next line.

Answer (score 4):

Another option if you do not want to rely on CSS for any reason is using the *non-breaking space*: `&nbsp;`, `&#160;` or `&nbsp;`

(see [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) for more information about it)