# How to transition (rotate) individual letters of a sentence for major browsers (also Chrome)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, d3.js

I want to output a sentence. When the sentence appears all individual letters should appear by rotating and getting larger.

My approach was the following:
What I did was to split up the sentence and put every letter in an individual `span` element. Then I transition the letters by using the ccs transform `-webkit-transform`. However, this doesn't work in Chrome unless you set you `display: inline-block`. Then the rotation works as intended, however the spaces are not displayed any more. This results in all words being tied together.

See below or [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ee2todev/vwze2ad4/19/)

```js
let containerDiv = "div.chart";

function displayText(_textArray) {
  let sel = d3.select(containerDiv);

  // add headers for all strings but the last one
  for (let i = 0; i < _textArray.length - 1; i++) {
    sel.append("div")
        .attr("class", "header h" + i)
      .append("h1")
        .attr("class", "trans")
        .text(_textArray[i]); 
  }

  // add last string by wrapping each letter around a span
  // which can be styled individually
  let sel2 = sel.append("div")
        .attr("class", "header h" + (_textArray.length - 1))
      .append("h1")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .attr("class", "trans");

  const lastString = _textArray[_textArray.length-1];
  for (let i = 0; i < lastString.length; i++) {
    sel2.append("span")
      .attr("class", "color-" + (i % 5))
      .text(lastString[i]); 
  }
}

function transitionLetters(_selection){
   _selection
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .delay((d,i) => i * 200)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("-webkit-transform", "rotate(-720deg) scale(1)");
}

let myText = ["I like to eat", "ham and eggs"];
displayText(myText);
d3.selectAll("span").call(transitionLetters);
```

```css
div.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: max-content;
}

h1 span {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-0deg) scale(0.001);
}

.color-0 { color: rgb(255, 0, 171); }
.color-1 { color: rgb(0, 168, 255); }
.color-2 { color: rgb(171, 0, 255); }
.color-3 { color: rgb(255, 171, 0); }
.color-4 { color: rgb(168, 255, 0); }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
    <div class="chart"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces are there, they just aren't shown because a span won't show content that is only white space.

```
span { /* or some custom class for those spans */
    white-space:pre;
}
```

from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742967/7355135

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the whitespaces, try adding the **white-space:pre** declaration to your h1 span selector.

```
 h1 span {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-0deg) scale(0.001);
  white-space:pre;
}
```

This post provide a summary and link for different options regarding how to deal with white spaces with css: [how to make space within span show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742946/how-to-make-space-within-span-show-up)