# Rendering Tree using d3 and java-script

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to render a tree (with lots of text as labels) using the following code:

```
      .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 3px;
      }

      .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

      .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
```

javascript:

```
    var margin = {top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
      width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var i = 0;

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
      .size([height, width]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
      .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    root = treeData[0];

    update(root);

    function update(source) {

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });

      // Declare the nodes…
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

      // Enter the nodes.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

      nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "#fff");

      nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.names; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // Declare the links…
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

      // Enter the links.
      link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    }
```

My problem is that text that I need to display (contained in the field 'names' is a small paragraph with carriage returns).  When d3 renders this in puts everything in one line i.e is not respecting the carrige returns in the text. How do I fix this?

Comment: in the css for the text add `white-space: pre` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286349/how-to-transition-rotate-individual-letters-of-a-sentence-for-major-browsers/49287506#49287506)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transition (rotate) individual letters of a sentence for major browsers (also Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286349/how-to-transition-rotate-individual-letters-of-a-sentence-for-major-browsers)